# jQuery validate: require either a single field or a separate pair, or both

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a simple form that has three fields: email, first name, and last name. I would like to require that the user enter either their email, BOTH their first and last names, or all three fields. Ideally, I would like to display the following error messages:

- if they click submit with all fields blank, a generic message indicating they must enter either email, first and last name, or all three
- if they enter just a first name, a message indicating they need to enter their last as well, and vice versa

I am using jQuery Validate and am having a hard time accomplishing this. It seems a simple task if there are just two fields, with a user needing to enter either one or the other, or both. But I can't seem to find any solutions for my situation. Here's what I have so far (not much at all):

**HTML:**

```
    <form id="myform">
      <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
      <br />
      <input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" placeholder="First name">
      <br />
      <input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name" placeholder="Last name">
      <br />
      <br />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
```

**Javascript:**

```
    $('#myform').validate({
      rules: {
        email: {


        },
        first_name: {
          required: function (element) {
            return !$("#last_name").is(":blank");
          }
        },
        last_name: {
          required: function (element) {
            return !$("#first_name").is(":blank");
          }
        }
      }
    });
```

And here's the associated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kcstricks/L1w8vje6/).

How would I go about getting the functionality I need?

Comment: You could have the validate unhide a div with a message for each field that fails validate instead of returning.

Comment: @mkaatman - I don't quite follow what you mean by "instead of returning". Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Your validate function returns true/false. Instead of doing that, you could add logic that would show/hide a div with an error message for that field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use the `require_from_group` method/rule (part of [the `additional-methods.js` file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.14.0/additional-methods.js)) to require that at least one of your three fields is filled out.  Then keep your `required` conditional logic to ensure that `first_name` is mandated if `last_name` is filled out and vice-versa.

```
$('#myform').validate({
    rules: {
        email: {
            require_from_group: [1, '.mygroup']
        },
        first_name: {
            require_from_group: [1, '.mygroup'],
            required: function(element) {
                return !$("#last_name").is(":blank");
            }
        },
        last_name: {
            require_from_group: [1, '.mygroup'],
            required: function(element) {
                return !$("#first_name").is(":blank");
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**Working DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/dct0c3u1/**

---

Look at the [`errorPlacement`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#errorplacement), [`groups`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#groups), [`invalidHandler`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#invalidhandler), and [`showErrors`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#showerrors) callback functions to get more control over how/where your messages are displayed.

Example:

```
    showErrors: function() {
        // using this callback to suppress default messages
        return false;
    },
    invalidHandler: function() {
        if (validate.numberOfInvalids() === 3) {
            $("#errorbox").html("enter either email, first and last name, or all three");

        } else {
            $("#errorbox").html("");
            validate.defaultShowErrors(); // show default messages
        }
    }
```

**DEMO 2:  http://jsfiddle.net/sfte41jt/**

For even greater control, see the `.showErrors()` method where you can programmatically toggle a message...

http://jqueryvalidation.org/Validator.showErrors/

Comment: Thanks! I was able to get close to the behavior that I wanted using your strategy. Is there a natural way (i.e. built into jQuery validate) to control errors such that if all fields cause an error (as is the case if all are left blank) a single error message is displayed, while still maintaining the ability to display unique errors below each error-causing field when, say, only one or two of the fields cause an error?  What I ended up doing is grouping all the fields so that I only display a single error when all three fields are erroneous, but this forced me to display all errors in one place

Comment: @kcstricks, like I stated in my answer, you would use a combination of callback functions to control the error messages.  You can also put conditionals inside the callbacks so that things only happen when there is an error on certain field(s).  However, you're asking for a single error when the whole form is empty while also having individual errors on each field... it's logically contradictory.  There is nothing in this plugin that knows when an *entire* form is blank... it only knows when the form is invalid (one or more fields are invalid/blank).

Comment: @kcstricks, you could use `invalidHandler` and count the number of errors using `.numberOfInvalids()`.   If it's `3` do a single message... if it's less than `3`, do `.defaultShowErrors()` which will show the individual messages.  See my edited answer.

Comment: This is precisely what I need! Thank you for your dedicated efforts :)